# insert border-color to image link in yahoo mail

Tags: email, border, inline, yahoo, newsletter

I'm creating a newsletter and I observed that in Yahoo mail a blue border is added to the images inside a link. I already checked other forums and you can solve this by applying any of these two options in the CSS inline:

```
border:none;
border:0;
```

This does work and you wont see the blue border on yahoo mail. The problem is that for my design I want to add a border-color to the image as link. So if I apply this solution for Yahoo mail I will have no border on the images.

Is there any way which I can solve this issue?

Here you have my code:

```
   <tr> 
       <td width="260px"> 
             <a href="#"> 
               <img alt="" src="link-to-image/pic1.jpg" style="width:258px;border: rgba(235, 173, 21, 0.5) 1px solid;display:block;" /> 
             </a> 
        </td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `border="1" border-color="#005288"` in your image tag. Always use the 6-digit hex code also.

Comment: isn;t this exactly the same as border="#005288 1px solid"? That what I have at this moment with a rgba color property. What would happen if I insert both? Which one overules?

Comment: Combining the hex tag with the border type and width isn't supported across all email clients. Silly I know, but my technique works best. You have to declare them separate and border is more consistent declared in HTML. Never tried combining both techniques with different color values, so you'd have to test that.